# How to update file links in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel sheet I have some files linked to it, these files are from two folders c/desktop/2022/user, c/desktop/2022/source - old folder . These files filename are in column j . Now I want to write a macro that automatically updates the files linked in excel with corresponding files whose filenames are in column d and these files can be found in folder c/desktop/2023/user , c/desktop/2023/source- new folder.

I tried the below macro, but the code takes me to the folder location c/desktop/2023/user to select the file to update the file links for each of the file. I want this to be done by the macro itself also I want the code look for files in two folder c/desktop/2023/user/, c/desktop/2023/source

```
Sub UpdateLinks()
    Dim oldFileName As String
    Dim newFilePath As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Iterate through all rows in Column J
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
        ' Check if the cell in Column J is not empty
        If Cells(i, 10).Value <> "" Then
            ' Get the old file name
            oldFileName = Cells(i, 10).Value
            
            ' Get the new file path from Column D
            newFilePath = "c/desktop/2023/user" & Cells(i, 4).Value
            
            ' Update the link
            On Error Resume Next
            ThisWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=oldFileName, NewName:=newFilePath, Type:=xlExcelLinks
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your filename cell have the `/` at the start of the filename?  It's missing from `newFilePath = "c/desktop/2023/user" & Cells(i, 4).Value` which will return something like _c/desktop/2023/user12345.xlsx_ rather than _c/desktop/2023/user/12345.xlsx_

Comment: the file name does not have / at the start....I have just included / in newFilePath = "c/desktop/2023/user/" & Cells(i, 4).Value

Comment: Did that stop it asking you for the location?  It won't search the two folders, but should now work if the file is in the `user` folder.  I'd also remove the `On Error Resume Next` - if the link update fails this will hide the error message and the user will think everything worked ok.  Best to display a message if the file can't be found.

Comment: yes, but the code takes me to the folder c/desktop/2023/user/ and now I have to select the file with which I want to update the file , so basically the code is going to data> edit link>selecting the file>choosing update link>going the folder c/desktop/2023/user/ and then from here I have manually choose the file which I want to be done  by the code itself.